# restricting values for a string member variable

Tags: java

A string variable in Java can take one of the three values type=start, type=data, type=end ..
what would be the best way to make sure it never gets set to any other value except start or data or end ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an Enum instead of a String.

Failing that, make it a private member and use a setter method that validates the value.  Of course, this won't protect you against code within the class itself directly setting the value.

Comment: To be more precise, an enum allows you to check at compile time when any other solution will check at runtime (and throw an IllegalArgumentException for example)...